# How to get id data from another table in Flask with Mysql

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I want to ask, how do I get data from another table in Flask.  for example I want to take the author's data in the author's table to be added to the book table with a combo box, so we only select the author's id and the author's name will automatically appear on the form to add the book's data.

i try like this

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Author :</label>
     <select name="" id="">
       {% for row in tb_author %}
       <option value="{{row.0}}"></option>
       {% endfor %}
     </select>
</div>
```

in my database

```
author_table
field : id (pk)------------ i want to get data from this table
        author name       |
                          | (connected)
book_table                |  
field : book_id (pk)      |
        author_id (fk)----- to this table
        book_title
        price
```

Comment: Since Flask does not come with any database you will have to tell us what you are using and how your structure / model looks.

Comment: Did you mean a database model ? Or something else...?

Answer (score 0):

Flask itself does not manage a database, but it allows you to connect a database to a database. You can attach this database to the persistent `g` object. Please see the tutorial here:
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/tutorial/database/?highlight=database

You can query the database using from this persistent

```
g.db.execute('SELECT id FROM author_table').fetchall()
```

or

```
g.db.execute(
    'SELECT name, author.name FROM book_table 
    inner join (select id, name from author_table where name = "JK Rowling") author
    on author.id=book_table.author_id'
).fetchall()
```

(code not run syntax/logic may be off)

If you are looking to add this kind of data into one of your templates/webpages, you can specify the data you want to provide to the html table by passing it through the `render_template` function provided by Flask, and then in the template, operating on the data through the flask smart-template processing syntax. 
Eg:
`render_template('authors_and_books.html', author_books=[['author1','book1'],['author1','book2'],['author2','book3']...])`
and

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Book</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    {% for author,book in authors_books %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ author }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ book }}
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```